# How to send pointer input to c++ program using python?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, boost-python, ros

I have a function in c++ that returns vector. I am using BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE to call it from python. I want to send a pointer as input to the c++ function. I was trying to send the pointer as string. I know this is the worst method but some people are using it and it is working fine. For my case it isn't working. I am new in c++.

Working case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s1 = "0x7fff3e8aee1c";
    stringstream ss;
    ss << s1;
    cout << "ss : " << ss << endl;
    long long unsigned int i;
    ss >> hex >> i;
    cout << "i : " << i << endl;
    int *i_ptr=reinterpret_cast<int *>(i);
    cout << "pointer: " << i_ptr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My case:

```
#include "openrave-core.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "valid_grasp_generator/GraspSnapshot.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <sstream>
using namespace OpenRAVE;
using namespace std;

boost::python::list get_penetration_depth(string env)
{
    vector<double> vec(9,0);
    stringstream ss(env);
    long long unsigned int i;
    ss >> hex >> i;
    EnvironmentBasePtr penv = reinterpret_cast<int *>(i);


    //code for getting penetration value from the openrave

    typename std::vector<double>::iterator iter;
    boost::python::list list;
    for (iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter) {
        list.append(*iter);
    }
    return list;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libdepth_penetration){
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("get_penetration", get_penetration_depth);
}
```

Error during catkin_make:

```
/home/saurabh/catkin_ws/src/valid_grasp_generator/src/depth_penetration.cpp: In function ‘boost::python::list get_penetration_depth(std::string)’:
/home/saurabh/catkin_ws/src/valid_grasp_generator/src/depth_penetration.cpp:37:56: error: conversion from ‘int*’ to non-scalar type ‘OpenRAVE::EnvironmentBasePtr {aka boost::shared_ptr<OpenRAVE::EnvironmentBase>}’ requested
     EnvironmentBasePtr penv = reinterpret_cast<int *>(i);
                                                        ^
make[2]: *** [valid_grasp_generator/CMakeFiles/depth_penetration.dir/src/depth_penetration.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [valid_grasp_generator/CMakeFiles/depth_penetration.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you try a wrong conversion between an `int` to a `shared_ptr`:

```
EnvironmentBasePtr penv = reinterpret_cast<int *>(i); // wrong conversion
// where EnvironmentBasePtr is boost::shared_ptr<EnvironmentBase>
```

For this conversion I suggest using a constructor of `shared_ptr` and `a null deleter`. I see 3 possible solutions.

You can define your **own null deleter** `void deleter(void* ptr) {}` then  :

```
boost::shared_ptr<EnvironmentBase> penv(reinterpret_cast<EnvironmentBase *>(i),&deleter);
```

If your **boost is 1.55 or less**, you can include `<boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>` then :

```
boost::shared_ptr<EnvironmentBase> penv(reinterpret_cast<EnvironmentBase *>(i),boost::serialization::null_deleter());
```

If your **boost is 1.56 or more**, you can include `<boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>` then :

```
boost::shared_ptr<EnvironmentBase> penv(reinterpret_cast<EnvironmentBase *>(i),boost:null_deleter());
```